# php mod rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i got a Q regarding mod_rewrite with php.

currently my userprofile php page has the following link to determine a user:
domain.com?username=john

i would need to convert this url into like this:
domain.com/john.

how can i do this in mod_rewrite??

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain.com/(.*)$ domain.com/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: hi, tks. i tried but it gave a page not found..i put this: RewriteRule ^domain.com/profile/(.*) domain.com/profile.php?username=$1

Comment: You have to change 'domain.com' to your own domain name ofcourse.

Comment: hi midas, its okay. I 've posted a solution i found. please check it out. =)

Comment: Try again, I forgot the `$` (`^domain.com/(.*)$`).

Comment: @Midas - I too am running into the same issue, not sure what the problem is but within my directory, the variable after the / continues to try and pull a file as opposed to the htaccess rule

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The initial problem was my profile php page has the following link: domain.com/profile.php?username=john

instead of this, i would need to make it easy to read url like this: domain.com/john.

what i did is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I'm not sure if this has any security breach but do leave your feedback

Comment: how did you get this to work? mine keeps trying to take the variable and treat it like an actual page